# Java username and password validation with Database

Tags: java, database, authentication

I am trying to validate user input with database information.  So if a user enters a username it will check to see if there is a match with the database.

```
public void login() throws SQLException {
        boolean loginUsername = false;
        boolean loginPassword = false;
        String input = null;

        while(input == null) {
            System.out.println(message.loginUsername());
            input = in.nextLine();

            try {
                preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM doom.accounts;");
                rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()) {
                    String username = rs.getString("username");

                    if(!input.equals(username)) {
                        System.out.println(message.invalidUsername());
                        input = null;
                    } else {
                        loginUsername = true;
                    }
                }
            } catch(SQLException e) {

            } finally {
                if(statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I posted just the username part of the method.  I have debugged and can confirm that my user input does equal a valid username from the database but I am still getting invalid username message when it shouldnt.

Comment: Since you're using a database, why not let the database look for a row in the table with the correct username using a `where` clause in your SQL statement? It's much more efficient.

Comment: heed @hexafraction's advice.   Very inefficient the way you're doing it.

Comment: The column name from the database may be coming back as `USERNAME` not `username`, so try `rs.getString("USERNAME")` or `rs.getString(1)`. And use a `where` clause like @hexafraction said.

Comment: And, depending on the database you are using the `;` in the `select` statement is probably unnecessary and may cause you a problem.

Comment: also if there is a way more efficient way to this please explain or post links!

Comment: You are potentionally comparing input with everry username from the table, and if one doesn't march you get the message. You should also get an NPE in the next round. Or you have left out too much... and of course you should use a WHERE clause

Comment: You're not handling the SQLException. Handle that for sure. Don't just ignore it. And while (input == null)? What's that about? That makes no sense. You go ahead and try to call the database, even if your input is null anyway. And if it's non null, but invalid, then you're having to force input to be null in order to try again. Odd way of doing your validation. And use a where clause in your search, but be cautious of SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Test it by writing the SQL Query and also when you do the equals check in the string make sure that the cases are same in both the String.

You can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` if the cases are not important.

Better approach will be to change your query to this:

```
 select username from doom.accounts where username like ?
```

Remember to leave out the ';'

Take a look at preparedStatement and set the user name in the `?`

You can have a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-object-example.htm).